# Issue On Setting Session Using Ajax, jQuery, and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a simple Ajax Login system and I have a jQuery Ajax call in my login.php as:

```
 if(proceed){
   var data = 'email='+tempEmail+'&pass='+tempPass; 
    var loginreq = $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url : "assets/tempusers.php",
                            cache: false,
                            data: data
                           });
  loginreq.done(function(html) {
  if(html=='true'){
     window.location.replace('app.php');
  }
  else  {
        $("#loginRequest").before('<div class="alert alert-danger err" role="alert">Email or Password Is Not Correct</div>');
   }
  });    
 }
```

The `tempusers.php` File is like:

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'conconfig.php';
$con = new mysqli(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASS,DB_NAME);

 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $pass =  $_POST['pass'];

 $query = "SELECT * FROM tempusers WHERE user='$email' AND pass='$pass'";
 $result = mysqli_query($con,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
 $num_row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
 $row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
 if( $num_row >=1 ) {
  echo 'true';
     $_SESSION['uName'] = $row['uName'];
  }
 else{
  echo 'false';
 }
?>
```

and in my app.php I have

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(!empty($_SESSION['uName'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
 }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Secret Land</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <h1>Hi This is App</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am sure that I am inputting correct User Email ans Password into the boxes but the app.php is not showing up! I am not getting any error message either.

When I remove the beginning part of the app.php from the page every thing works fine!

```
<?php
 session_start();
 if(!empty($_SESSION['uName'])){
    header('Location: login.php');
 }
?>
```

Can you please let me know what i am doing wrong and what is causing this issue?

Comment: Are you storing passwords as a plain text in the db? are they encrypted/hashed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If valid login

```
$_SESSION['uName'] = $row['uName'];
```

so yes, it is NOT empty

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['uName']))
```

suppose it should be

```
if(empty($_SESSION['uName']))
```

right? :)